# GTM script in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have put this script in body tag of index.html

```
<noscript>
      <iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-KMXH6S"
              height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
    </noscript>
    <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
      new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
      j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
      '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');
    </script>
```

But it stays there as it is and the script from GTM never loads.What else do I need to do?

Comment: `But it stays there as it is`: can you explain a bit more?  Where are you putting the tag exactly?

Comment: @DavinTryon: I am putting it in body tag. How should I know if zopim script was imported using GTM?

Comment: I get $zopim is not defined so I believe GTM tags are not working?

Comment: I am trying to load zopim through GTML and I get $zopim is not defined so I believe GTM tags are not working?

Comment: Sorry but what has this snippet got to do with React? Secondly, just a sanity check, but did you change GTM-XXXXXX in your code?

Comment: @YangShun Yes, I have changed that to correct one. I am not sure how to integrate this in React. In vanilla js, we just add this script for gtm's. Not sure how this works wth react. I am also trying react google tag manager but no luck